# Prolog: calculate variable making pairs in list all distinct

Tags: prolog

I have a list with all pairs consist of 1..3 and hope all the pairs in list are distinct with each other. For example, for the below fact, the expected result is

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

However, with my function, it seems Prolog does not derive that variable, the output is still with temp variable `_4848` instead of number 2.

```
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 3], [_4848, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

Below is my function as reference:

```
Grid([[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[1,3],[_,3],[3,1],[3,2],[2,2],[3,3]]).

completegrid(G) :- 
    append(G, Vs), 
    Vs ins 1..3,
    is_set(G).
```

And I run it with

```
Grid(G), completegrid(G).
```

Anyone may explain this? Thank you.

Comment: May you explain more? I am really a new beginner of Prolog. I thought is_set will derive logic to find exact value of _4848. Why G is a list will prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common mistake people make with `clpfd` is that statements like:

```
X in 1..3
```

do **not** assign values to `X`. It adds a *constraint* to `X`. If we write this in the terminal, we obtain:

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.

?- X in 1..3.
X in 1..3.
```

It is only when you call `label/1` with a list of variables, Prolog will search for configurations for the variables such that these constraints are validated.

Since you do not ground `X`, the list past to `is_set/1`, will still contain a free variable. Now `is_set` performs a duplicate check on the items, but it checks only if the terms are fully equal. So `is_set([X,Y])` is considered true, and so is `is_set([[1,2],[1,X]])`. It does *not* add a constraint that `X` should be different from `X`.

There is however a `dif/2` predicate, that allows use to represent difference constraints. We can define our `dif_all/1` predicate:

```
dif_all([]).
dif_all([H|T]) :-
    maplist(dif(H),T),
    dif_all(T).
```

and now our program can be altered to:

```
completegrid(G) :- 
    append(G, Vs),
    Vs ins 1..3,
    dif_all(G),
    label(G).
```

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation! Just wonder if you have any idea about soduko question I commented in previous answer? Thanks.

Comment: Because `all_distinct` has propagation: in case you write `X in 1..3, X #< 2`, then Prolog can automatically reduce the domain of `X` and finds out `X = 1`. Since the constraints are here sufficient not to backtrack, it works. Compare it to you solving an "*easy*" sudoku: did you ever had to try out a variable and then later backtrack?

Comment: Yea, I have tried some basic examples. I am attempted to solve an irregular sudoku, so I am testing some stuff to understand how normal sudoku works. Thanks, it's clear now.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems in your implementation,firstly facts can't start with capital so:

```
Grid([[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[1,3],[_,3],[3,1],[3,2],[2,2],[3,3]]).
```

should be:

```
grid([[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[1,3],[_,3],[3,1],[3,2],[2,2],[3,3]]).
```

else it will give **syntax error**, same with `Grid(G), completegrid(G).` should be: `grid(G), completegrid(G)`.

The second and most important error is that `Vs ins 1..3` sets a constraint in elements of Vs but it **does not evaluate**, so variables will remain variables (constrained to value 1..3 when instantiated), you need to use `label/2` for instantiation:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

grid([[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[1,3],[_,3],[3,1],[3,2],[2,2],[3,3]]).

completegrid(G) :- 
  append(G, Vs), 
  Vs ins 1..3, label(Vs),
  is_set(G).
```

Example:

```
?- grid(G), completegrid(G).
G = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3]] ;
false.
```

One more important thing:

> **is_set/2 is nonmonotonic**

This means that where you place constraints that affect the argument of `is_set/2` affect the behavior of the predicate e.g:

```
completegrid(G) :- 
  append(G, Vs), 
  Vs ins 1..3,
  is_set(G),label(Vs).
            ^^^^^^
```

Now of you try:

```
?- grid(G), completegrid(G).
G = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 3], [1, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [2|...], [...|...]] [write]
G = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 3], [1, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3]] ;%WRONG !!
G = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3]] ;
G = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 3], [3, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [2, 2], [3, 3]]. %WRONG !!
```

Comment: Thank you! It's clear now. And may i ask one more question, for example here [Soduko](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd-sudoku). On second line of soduko predicate, it uses ins 1..9 but not uses label, why it works?

Comment: Try this: `?- Vs = [1,X,2], Vs ins 1..3, all_distinct(Vs).
Vs = [1, 3, 2],
X = 3.  ` and 

`?- Vs = [1,X,2], Vs ins 1..3, is_set(Vs).
Vs = [1, X, 2],
X in 1..3.` Do you see the difference?

Comment: That's because `all_distinct/2` belongs to lib CLPFD which allows reasoning in Variables while `is_set/2` can't, though in your problem as stated it wouldn't be so easy to use `all_distinct(G)` since G is a list of lists and all_different requires a list of integers...